# list comprehension with packed tuples

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have two lists.

```
list_1 = [[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 2, 0, 0]]
list_2 = [(1,'A'), (2,'B'), (3,'C'), (4,'D')]
```

I want to generate a new list, list_3.

```
[[(1, 'A'), (4, 'D')], [(2, 'B'), (2, 'B')]]
```

I wanted to use list comprehension.

```
list_3 = [[list_2[index]*val for index, val in enumerate(elem) if val > 0] for elem in list_1]
```

But it generated:

```
[[(1, 'A'), (4, 'D')], [(2, 'B', 2, 'B')]]
```

You can see that in the second term tuple is unpacked. How can keep tuple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list_1 = [[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 2, 0, 0]]
list_2 = [(1,'A'), (2,'B'), (3,'C'), (4,'D')]
list_3 = [
    [
        item
        for index, val in enumerate(elem) if val > 0
        for item in [list_2[index]] * val
    ]
    for elem in list_1
]
print(list_3)
# [[(1, 'A'), (4, 'D')], [(2, 'B'), (2, 'B')]]
```